# Frameset in frameset border hell

Tags: html, coding-style, border, frame, frameset

I have a web page with lots of framesets and frames (don't ask), and I want to be able to show frame borders where the red borders appear in the mockup below (The vertical borders must be scrollable).

If I set `frameborder="0"` to the `#outer` frameset (i don't want any border to appear there), this prevents me from overriding it in the `#middle` frameset. Please not that there should not be a border in the `#innerXXX` framesets.

So, how can I show frame borders on the `#innerXXX` framesets? (only where the red lines are visible in the mockup)

Thanks.

P.S. Don't ask.

[image: This is what I want to appear]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>Frame desperation</title>

</head>

<frameset id="outer" rows="23, *" frameborder="0" border="0">
  <frame noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" src="http://www.bing.com">
  <frameset id="middle" cols="20,30%,35%,35%" frameborder="5" border="5"  bordercolor="red" id="sizingControl">
      <frame name="minimizeBar" noresize="noresize" id="minimizeBar" scrolling="no" src="http://www.bing.com">
      <frameset id="inner1" rows="146,*,20" border-top="0" border-bottom="0" id="treePanel">
        <frame id="treeToolbar" name="treeToolbar" scrolling="no" src="http://www.bing.com">
        <frame id="treeContent" name="treeContent" src="http://www.bing.com">
        <frame id="treeStatus" name="treeStatus" scrolling="no" src="http://www.bing.com">
      </frameset>
      <frameset id="inner2 rows="146,*,20" frameborder="0" border="0" >
        <frame id="leftToolbar" name="leftToolbar" scrolling="no" src="http://www.bing.com">
        <frame id="leftDocumentContent" name="leftDocumentContent" src="http://www.bing.com">
        <frame id="leftStatus" name="leftStatus" scrolling="no" src="http://www.bing.com">
      </frameset>
      <frameset id="inner3 rows="146,*,20" frameborder="0" border="0" >
        <frame id="rightToolbar" name="rightToolbar" scrolling="no" src="http://www.bing.com">
        <frame id="rightDocumentContent" name="rightDocumentContent" src="http://www.bing.com">
        <frame id="rightStatus" name="rightStatus" scrolling="no" src="http://www.bing.com">
      </frameset>
  </frameset>
</frameset>
<noframes></noframes>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "borders", do you mean frame borders (to resize the frames), or just graphical borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have frameborders on framesets, just on frames themselves, so the best way to do this would probably to have a single frameset containing five frames - one at the top, one at the far left and three in the middle. You give the ones in the middle a frameborder. Then each middle frame points to an separate file which has a single frameset containing three frames - top, middle bottom. In other words:

- Frameset

  - Frame (top)
  - Frame (left)
  - Frame (inner1) - add frame border

    - Frameset (in separate file)

      - Frame (top)
      - Frame (middle)
      - Frame (bottom)
  - Frame (inner2) - add frame border

    - Frameset (in separate file)

      - Frame (top)
      - Frame (middle)
      - Frame (bottom)
  - Frame (inner3) - add frame border

    - Frameset (in separate file)

      - Frame (top)
      - Frame (middle)
      - Frame (bottom)

Incidentally, regarding the code itself, there are missing quotation marks after inner2 and inner3. Also, you shouldn't have two IDs in a single element as this could mess up any JavaScript or CSS you write. Good luck with all those frames - you have my sympathy!

Comment: A frame cannot contain a frameset or any other content between its opening and closing tags. [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.2.2)

Comment: I should have explained better - I meant the inner frames have separate files as their sources. These files each contain a single frameset that contain three further frames. Have updated the tree to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). Another problem with this application is that it has a lot of Javascript written for it, which assumes the current structure of frames and framesets. I was hoping that the by playing with the frameborder attribute I could make the borders appear where I wanted them. I will check this as accepted if something easier does not come up.

Comment: Marking as answer, as I could not find a way to show the borders I wanted without changing the current structure.